Seeking Assurances on getDisplayMedia Security and Local-Only Data Handling
Hello and thank you in advanced,
I am using the getDisplayMedia method (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getDisplayMedia) to capture a screen recording or screenshot (with the user’s consent) that may include sensitive information. This data will be uploaded to our app for processing.
Our legal and compliance team is concerned that the getDisplayMedia function might send this captured data to the browser company or other third parties, rather than keeping it confined to the local device. While we do not believe this to be the case, our legal team is seeking official documentation or assurances that this functionality operates exclusively on the user's local machine and that no third-party transmission occurs unless explicitly programmed.
Does such documentation exist to confirm that getDisplayMedia is local-only and that captured data is not sent elsewhere by default? Additionally, is there guidance we can use to show how this data is handled securely and deleted when the browser session ends?
We have tried searching for documentation on how the data is stored in mdn, w3c and other sources but have not been able to find anything explicitly stating how the data is handled. I have also created a demo of how things are stored in browser memory but that has not been sufficient.
Thank you.
